# why shipping calculation does not work in Netsuite transaction estimate for fed ex 2 day?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

while creating a new estimate in Netsuite suite script with specifying the shipping method returns an error with the following message
*Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate. The rate for this service is not available for the specified source and destination addresses.*

Can we reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple locations set up? Have you selected a location for the estimate and a ship to address?